# How to prevent scrolling of multiple UIScrollView objects at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

Here is my situation:
I have 2 UIScrollView objects. Horizontal scrolling is enabled for both of them. Their frames are not overlapped. Both objects are subviews of the same view:

```
 ..................................................
 |                                                |
 |                      UIView                    |
 |                                                |
 |                                                |
 |    ........................................    |
 |    |                                      |    |
 |    |             UIScrollView 1           |    |
 |    |                                      |    |
 |    |......................................|    |
 |                                                |
 |    ........................................    |
 |    |                                      |    |
 |    |             UIScrollView 2           |    |
 |    |                                      |    |
 |    |......................................|    |
 |                                                |
 |................................................|
```

The problem is that they are both scrollable at the same time.
How can I prevent scrolling of first UIScrollView object if scrolling in second object is already started?

Comment: Have you tried using `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`? You can put some checks in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` and return `true` or `false` depending on certain situations.

Comment: @Eendje yes I tried to use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, but UIScrollView doesn't allow to change delegate of its pan gesture recognizer: it crashes with comment that UIScrollView should be delegate of its recognizer.

Comment: I believe there were some work arounds, e.g. add a new pan gesture to the scroll view and make it fail the gesture of the scrollview. This way you can play with the delegate of the new pan gesture. Another option would be to disable `scrollEnabled` when the other is scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    [tableView1, tableView2].forEach { if scrollView != $0 { $0.scrollEnabled = false } }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    [tableView1, tableView2].forEach { $0.scrollEnabled = true }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    [tableView1, tableView2].forEach { $0.scrollEnabled = true }
}
```

You'll probably have to fine tune it because there are still to consider.

---

Originally I wanted to use:

```
tableView2.scrollEnabled = scrollView == tableView1
```

But sometimes it would still scroll (maybe it won't on an actual device), so I used the second method to check when the scrolling has ended.